# Every group of order p^2 is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

I am studying for my algebra qualifying exam in January, and I have a question regarding the proof I have for this question in Hungerford, problem 13 under the Sylow Theorems section.

The way I approached it is as follows:

By the third Sylow theorem, the number of Sylow p-subgroups divides $|G|$ and is of the form $pk+1$. The divisors of $p^2$ are $1$, $p$ and $p^2$. However, the only divisor of the form $pk+1$ is $1$ (when $k=0$). So, $G$ only has one Sylow p-subgroup, and therefore, by corollary 5.8, this Sylow p-subgroup has order $p^2$ and is normal. Meaning, the Sylow p-subgroup is the entire group $G$, and since it is normal, it is therefore abelian.

Is this correct, or do I need to use the hint like suggested? Thank you!

Comment: Please add the question itself, including the hint part, or those without the book wouldn’t be able to help you.

Comment: Any p-group is its own p-Sylow sugroup. This proves nothing.

Comment: Hint: If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian. Now consider possible cases for $|G/Z(G)|$.

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: Have you learned the class equation or Burnside’s theorem?

Comment: It’s more commonly called Burnside’s lemma.

Comment: Alex’s response helped a lot. Thank you all for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you suggesting that a normal subgroup is always abelian? I don't see how you are getting abelian from normal.

Here's a hint for a more typical solution to this problem: consider possible orders of $Z(G)$, and recall that for $p$-groups one has $Z(G)\neq\{1\}$.

Comment: Ok, I think that is what I thought but I did some reading on normal and abelian groups, and I see now that normal does not imply abelian. I will try the hint. Thank you!

Comment: @SarahHadaidi: It doesn't make sense to speak of "normal" groups. Asserting that $H$ is normal is meaningless. On the other hand, we can say that $H$ is a *normal subgroup* of $G$ – whether this is true depends on both the groups $H$ and $G$.